# I can´t execute code in the last fragment of a TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

My problem: I am following this link " https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout " to develop a sliding tab layout and get something like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZG9f.jpg)

I followed the guide and the SlideTabLayout seems to work pretty good, BUT. I´ve realize that if i try to make some code it works perfect in all the tabs but in the last one. I have to say i always use the same Fragment class, so the code should work on all the tabs.

For example, I´ve put a Log.e message in the fragment and i see the message in all the tabs but the last one.

After all i´ve tried following another guide using PagerTabStrip instead of TabLayout and I am having the same problem.
The fun part is the last page shows correctly the TextView with the page number.

Fragment pager adapter:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return PageFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return PageFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return PageFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}
```

Comment: there is no need to apologize for your use of the language. just ask your question, and some people in the community will do their best to help you make appropriate edits. please remove this apology from your question :)

Comment: Show your fragment pager adapter code

Comment: Done mate. This is the one I saw in the example with PagerTabStrip. I have realize when i start the activity two fragments are created. I read on other Stackoverflow post that it is normal, but it seems weird to me

Answer (score 1):

You see two fragments created because that is how `FragmentPagerAdapter` works to provide you a smooth transition between 2 tabs (2 fragments). I guess that your code may run for the first time, then it will not run if the fragment is already in memory. This is how Android says about **[FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html)**
`"This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of tabs. The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state"`